# The probability that any of the teams certainly win. The number of encounters which make this probability 98%.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> $N$  teams play a tournament in which every team plays every other team
>   exactly once. No ties occur, and each team has a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of
>   winning any game it plays.
>
> 1) What is the probability that one of the teams will finish the tournament without defeat?
>
> 2) How many times do you need to hold a tournament, so that with a probability of 98% at least once this happened?

My attempt:

**The first task:**

First of all, I need to get the overall number of games ${N\choose2} = \frac{N!}{2!\times(N-2)!} = \frac{(N-1)\times N}{2}$. Each game has the only 2 possible outcomes (win/lose) therefore the amount of possible outcomes is $2^\frac{(N-1)\times N}{2}$. It's the number of possible outcomes whilst each team has equal chances for win.

Let's suppose that some of the team wins in each game. Hence it has $(N-1)$ wins and the overall amount of possible undefined outcomes is $2^{\frac{(N-1)\times N}{2} - (N-1)}$. But this number of outcomes only for the some certain team,  so I have to multiply by number of the teams $N\times 2^{\frac{(N-1)\times N}{2} - (N-1)}$ it means the number of outcomes where one of the teams certainly wins.

According the above the probability $\frac{N\times 2^{\frac{(N-1)\times N}{2} - (N-1)}}{2^\frac{(N-1)\times N}{2}}$ eventually the probability is $N\times 2^{(1-N)}$.

Am I right at these?

**The second task**

If be honestly, I don't even know how to solve it. I mean how can be it solved with undefined number of teams. For instance, the case with 3 teams the probability much higher than the case with 15 teams. Hence the needed number of tournaments in the first case is fewer than in the second.

Also I supposed that it is the sum of probabilities like that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^x N\times 2^{(1-N)} = 0.98$ and we need to get $x$ but it seems foolish:)

Comment: You are correct that the second part cannot be answered without the number of teams being specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 (easier approach)

Only one team can win every match. Let this team be Team A. The probability that Team A wins every game is $\left(\frac 12 \right)^{N-1}$ because they play all $(N-1)$ other teams.

But the probability that a team wins every match $= P($Team A wins every match$)+P($Team B wins every match$)+...$

These are mutually exclusive events because only one team can win all matches.

Therefore $P($a team wins every match $)= N \times \left(\frac 12 \right)^{N-1}=N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}$ as you have correctly calculated.

Part 2

Hold the tournament $n$ times.

$P($this happens at least once$)=1-P($this never happens$)=1-\left(1- N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}\right)^n$

We want $1-\left(1- N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}\right)^n=0.98$

$\left(1- N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}\right)^n=0.02$

$n \log \left(1- N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}\right)=\log 0.02$

$n =\frac{\log 0.02}  {\log \left(1- N \times \left(2 \right)^{1-N}\right)} $

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's really helpful!